# What is proxy Agent

Tags: node.js, proxy, https-proxy-agent

```
 agent = toolData.withAgent ? proxyingAgent.create(accessTool.proxy, toolData.address) : null;
```

what is this proxyingAgent in my code. I have search about this on google but m still confused.
kindly explain this in easy wording, please don't use terminologies and domain language

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxying-agent

Answer (score 1):

A proxy agent is a network management element which acts as a middleman between a management system and an unmanaged device, allowing management by proxy. The proxy agent appears to the device or client as the server itself so it is also an element of security since the management server is completely invisible to connected devices.

You can further refer at: https://www.techopedia.com/definition/30733/proxy-agent

Comment: I read that article, explain to me your concept about this